# Pick a network share for NuGet's repositoryPath

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, nuget

We use a nuget.config file in the root of our source control. This way all solutions in this source control get to use the same nuget configuration and therefore the same repositoryPath where nuget downloads restored packages to use.

All across the internet, I find no mention of putting a network share as a repository path of nuget.config files. In my opinion it generally really does make sense to do so.

Why should every developer and build server have to download the nuget-packages from nuget.org themselves, when we could easily specify a single accessible location on e.g. \myTfsServer\Nuget\RepositoryPath?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <clear />
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="\\myTfsServer\Nuget\RepositoryPath" />
    </config>   
...
</configuration>
```

Is there something I clearly miss?

**UPDATE:**
I'm not talking about the sources. The location where a restore downloads all the packages to is what I am talking about. I don't want to check in my restored packages, so I try to bend the repositoryPath outside the source control...

Comment: Add repositoryPath to Nuget.config file works fine for me (e.g. %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config), the packages are restored to the shared folder instead of packages folder under solution. The changes will be affect when create a new project. For old project, you need to modify the references' path. Article: https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior Do you update references of existing project? What's the result if you create a new project?

Comment: Do you have any issue with "<add key="repositoryPath" value="\\myTfsServer\Nuget\RepositoryPath" />"? It works at my side.

Answer (score 1):

In nuget.config file, there are sections named [packageSources](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#packagesources) and [activePackageSource](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#activepackagesource).

**packageSources** lists all known package sources. **activePackageSource** identifies to the currently active source or indicates the aggregate of all sources.

To use a network share for NuGet's repositoryPath, you need to add a new key into `packageSources` and `activePackageSource` sections as below:

```
<packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="Network Share" value="\\myTfsServer\Nuget\RepositoryPath" />
</packageSources>


<activePackageSource>
    <add key="Network Share" value="\\myTfsServer\Nuget\RepositoryPath" />
</activePackageSource>
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the sources.

Comment: When your build project, Nuget package manager will find the packages under your solution folder, if it couldn't find the packages, it will get packages from the activePackageSource setting. You don't need to check in your restored packages, and it's not recommended to source controlled the packages.